# Como tornar meus programas C++ multi-arquitetura (32 e 64 bits)?

Tags: c, c++, mingw, arquitetura-computadores

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C++ nativo utilizando DevCPP e o compilador MinGW, ao executar a aplicação em outra máquina percebi um erro referente a arquitetura, pois meu programa só roda em 64-bits, como posso deixá-lo multi-arquitetura? Ou seja, fazê-lo rodar tanto em 64-bit quanto em 32-bit (sem fazer uma *build* para cada uma das arquiteturas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ padrão só gera códigos nativos para a arquitetura onde vai rodar, portanto não tem como rodar em arquitetura diferente. O único jeito é compilar para a arquitetura apropriada.

Claro que uma aplicação 32 bits poderia rodar em um sistema operacional 64 bits se este tiver alguma camada de compatibilidade. É o caso do Windows e de algumas distribuições do Linux. O oposto não é viável tecnicamente mesmo que alguém quisesse fazer, a não ser por uma emulação complexa e o resultado será horrível.

Só compilar para outra arquitetura pode não ser suficiente. O código precisa ser bem escrito para trabalhar bem em ambas, o problema pode estar aí.

Tecnicamente seria possível ter uma característica como do C# (código não nativo), mas ninguém se preocupou em fazer isso por não fazer muito sentido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Os binários serão diferentes, então não tem como aproveitar a mesma build exatamente.

É possível forçar a recompilação para as duas arquiteturas ao mesmo tempo, mas geralmente não é recomendável fazer isso já que você vai perder mais tempo compilando a arquitetura errada durante o desenvolvimento e pode fazer um script que gere a versão final para as duas arquiteturas no final...

Comment: Essa aplicação que estou desenvolvendo é dividido em cliente e servidor, o cliente é feito em C#.NET e o servidor em C++ nativo. No caso da parte cliente, no Visual Studio existe a opção Any CPU, por isso imaginei que talvez fosse possível deixar a aplicação c++ multi-arquitetura.

Comment: No caso se eu compilar para 32 bits, teoricamente uma máquina de 64 bits também poderia executá-lo, certo?

Comment: É possível sim. A arquitetura de 64bits é uma extensão da de 32bits. Porém, se estiver se integrando com outro software que em uma máquina é 32 bits e na outra é 64 bits, os acessos de memória poderão ser comprometidos.